# Is it possible to assign a variable to use in functions but it should not be global

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I'm trying to do is I need to assign a variable to use in several functions. But that variable should not be a global variable. How can I do that if it is possible?

Edit: I did forgot one thing. This is for my project and most of it is finished but this. **My code needs to be non-repeated as much as it can.** I have 5 variables and 15 functions to use some or all of that variables.

Edit2: Let me just post a function here.

```
def draw_stairs(top_stair_wide, stair_height, stair_count, character):
for o in range(stair_count):
    for b in range(stair_height):
        draw_straight_line(top_stair_wide, character)
        print("")
    top_stair_wide += 3
```

What I need to do is when I use that function, I need to fill "top_stair_wide", "stair_height", "stair_count" with **a variable that is not global**. I can't just put numbers because I will use those variables in 14 different functions again with maths.

I have a function that draws straight line and before, it inputs and returns character so those are not the problem.

Comment: just use **parameters** in your functions

Comment: It's recommended to show your code when post question

Comment: @Netwave as I understand, that would do but it would be too much repeated as I need to use same variables in different functions.

Comment: @buran I didn't post it because it's just a bunch of triangle-square, bow tie etc. drawing functions.

Comment: @OgulcanBozkurt to be honest I understand the question and its constraints but not why they are needed. You'll at least need one global variable somewhere (a dictionary), or maybe each function can return its result **and its input parameters** but then that makes every function cumbersome and unclear.

Comment: @Guimoute this is a project that our teacher gave us and he wants it without any global variables and without repeating the code too much. i just got a hint that it could be done with main function but i couldn't figure it out how.

Comment: Oh, with a main I see how to do, I'll write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a main function as you told me in a comment, you could write it like this:

```
def main():
    # Here are your NOT GLOBAL variables:
    top_stair_wide = 1
    stair_height = 2
    stair_count = 3
    character = "O"

    def draw_stairs(top_stair_wide, stair_height, stair_count, character):
        for o in range(stair_count):
            for b in range(stair_height):
                draw_straight_line(top_stair_wide, character)
                print("")
            top_stair_wide += 3

    # ... more definitions follow 

    # Then call the functions...

# Job done when you execute the program:
main()
```

Alternatively:

```
def main(top_stair_wide, stair_height, stair_count, character): # <-- cram all the expected arguments there

    def draw_stairs(top_stair_wide, stair_height, stair_count, character):
        for o in range(stair_count):
            for b in range(stair_height):
                draw_straight_line(top_stair_wide, character)
                print("")
            top_stair_wide += 3

    # ... more definitions follow 

    # Then call the functions...

# Job done when you execute the program:
main(1, 2, 3, "O")
```

It's also possible using kwargs, because then you have to know the arguments when you call main() and not when you define it:

```
def main(**kwargs):

    def draw_stairs(**kwargs):
        for o in range(kwargs["stair_count"]):
            for b in range(kwargs["stair_height"]):
                draw_straight_line(kwargs["top_stair_wide"], kwargs["character"])
                print("")
            kwargs["top_stair_wide"] += 3

    # ... more definitions follow 

    # Then call the functions...
    function1(**kwargs)
    function2(**kwargs)
    function3(**kwargs)


# Job done when you execute the program:
main(top_stair_wide = 1,
     stair_height = 2,
     stair_count = 3,
     character = "O")
```

Comment: alright i finally got it, thanks for 3 different methods :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a class, make the variables instance variables and turn the functions into methods. Then you can access the instance variables in each method without the explicit need to pass them around.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def add_them(self):
        return self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3

    def multiply_them(self):
        return self.var1 * self.var2 * self.var3
```

And so on.

Comment: it's good that I learned that but I am not allowed to use classes as we didn't learn them in school (I did myself).

Answer (score 2):

You need [parameter(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-parameter) in your function definition and then pass your variable(s) as [argument(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#argument) when you call it.

Comment: as I understand, I need to use parameters in every function that I defined right? if so, that would be so many repeats and I need non-repeated code.

Comment: @OgulcanBozkurt: You cam pass a container, like a dictionary, that has many parameter values in it. That way you only have to pass one argument.

Comment: @martineau wouldn't that whole dictionary called as one global variable?

Comment: No, in the function you will need to reference the argument passed. For example: with `def func(parms):` within the function's body you will need to used `parms['arg1']`, `parms['arg2']`, etc. A possibly better choice would be to use a [`collections.nametuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (or [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)) which would allow you to then write `parms.arg1` and `parms.arg2` which would be a little more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to your functions like:

```
def func1(variable):
    # your logic here with variable
    return 'something'

def func2(variable):
    # your logic here with variable
    return 'something'
```

Or you can set it as constant in current file as:

```
VARIABLE = 'variable'

def func1():
    # your logic here with VARIABLE
    return 'something'

def func2():
    # your logic here with VARIABLE
    return 'something'
```

Comment: `globals()['VARIABLE']` is `variable` so the second example doesn't fit. For the first example, the `'something'` should probably depend on `variable`.

Comment: Why is the second example not fitting? I did not understand what you wrote.

Comment: @Guimoute: Because `VARIABLE` is a constant defined in the global namespace. Which is specifically what OgulcanBozkurt doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a dictionary storing the shared parameters and only passing this dictionary (rather than all variables separately) as an argument:

```
def add_params(params):
   return params['var1'] + params['var2'] + params['var3']

def multiply_params(params):
   return params['var1'] * params['var2'] * params['var3']

>>> params = {'var1': 1, 'var2', 2, 'var3': 3}
>>> add_params(params)
6
>>> multiply_params(params)
6
```